# UIScrollView contains more views than exist when looping programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I'm resizing my scroll view's content size programmatically.  To do this, I look through all of the views contained within it and get the highest value for the view origin plus the view height, then set my content size to that plus 10.  For some reason, I have a lot of white space at the bottom of my page.  I used an `NSLog()` to find out what object it thought was this big and found that it is an object that does not even exist.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)resize_scrollview_to_fit {
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
        if (view.frame.size.height + view.frame.origin.y > scrollViewHeight) {
            scrollViewHeight = view.frame.size.height + view.frame.origin.y + 10;

            NSLog(@"Scroll View Height: %f \nView Type: %@", scrollViewHeight, view.class);
        }
    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollViewHeight))];
}
```

The output is:

```
2014-05-16 10:40:56.757 eTicket[5542:907] Scroll View Height: 175.000000 
View Type: UIImageView
2014-05-16 10:40:56.767 eTicket[5542:907] Scroll View Height: 301.000000 
View Type: UILabel
2014-05-16 10:40:56.773 eTicket[5542:907] Scroll View Height: 345.000000 
View Type: UITextField
2014-05-16 10:40:56.780 eTicket[5542:907] Scroll View Height: 399.000000 
View Type: UILabel
2014-05-16 10:40:56.787 eTicket[5542:907] Scroll View Height: 441.000000 
View Type: UILabel
2014-05-16 10:40:56.794 eTicket[5542:907] Scroll View Height: 520.000000 
View Type: UIImageView
```

There is only one UIImageView on this page within the scroll view, which is the first item listed.  That second UIImageView does not exist in either code or the storyboard.  The above code should end with the result of 441.  I have no code creating an UIImageView, and the only other 2 UIImageViews in the storyboard are on the same level as the UIScrollView and not within it.  Plus they would result in given 558 if it was seeing them.  So where is this extra UIImageView coming from, and how do I get rid of it?

Thanks,
James

**EDIT**

Are there really no other solutions for this?  I'd hate for Sasha's answer to be the only way to resolve this.  It just doesn't seem logical that a UIImageView would just be added automatically to a UIScrollView.  If his answer is correct though, can someone confirm it?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Why is it a Cocoa question?

Comment: @ElTomato I guess that's my own ignorance.  I assumed all programming for iPhone was done in the Cocoa framework.

Comment: Cocoa is an API package for Mac OS X. The API package equivalent to Cocoa that applies to iOS is Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your own track of subviews, don't rely on scroll view subviews. For example the second `UIImageView` might be a scroll indicator - an internal view, displayed when you scroll to track position.

Comment: What do you mean that I could keep my own track of sub views?  Do you mean to go ahead and connect them all to an IBOutlet variable?  That is definitely doable in this particular case, but I would hate for that the be the solution.  If I were making views dynamically I would not want to have to have a hard-coded value in there or keep a list of what views are active.  If you think that the extra UIImageView is a scroll indicator, is there a way to check for that?  Also, would that even be possible when no scrolling has occurred yet?

Comment: I mean that subviews of `UIScrollView` are not guaranteed to contain only views added by you. Although most of the time that probably would be the case. Sadly there is no way to check definitively if a particular view was not added by you. To be future-proof I would suggest using either `IBOutletCollection` or add subviews programmatically to a `NSMutableArray`