# Get a ScrollView all visible subViews for a rect?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I was implemented my own `UICollectionView` with a scrollView (to find why check my last questions).
It works great , and now i am trying to get this :

Get the current `ContentOffset` of the `scroller`, than discover what subviews are within this rect.

So one way to go is run on all of his subViews and check intersection something like :

```
for(UIView *view in [scroller subViews] )
if(view.frame viewIntersectsWithAnotherView:rect)
nslog(@"yes");
```

Is this good from performance aspect? is there a better way ? if this way is good, how exactly can i perform that ?

thanks.

Comment: its simple, you don't have to read my question, because i have asked here another question, and for her, i need an answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight forward implementation would be to iterate over all subviews – a separate array you keep track of. (Why not over `scrollView.subviews` – see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698297/uiscrollview-contains-more-views-than-exist-when-looping-programmatically)), the you would run a simple check

```
CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){self.contentOffset, self.bounds.size};
for (UIView *subview in self.registeredSubviews) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(visibleRect, subview.frame)) {
        // it's visible
    }
}
```

Now as for optimization

1. If you reckon this method will be called more often than user will scroll, use delegation methods to calculate and cache visible views upon scroll end
2. If you expect a table view - like logic in positioning of the cells, you might use binary search through the frames array to get visible cells in *O(log n)*
3. Lazy cache - calculate properties first time you need and reuse until the next time use scrolled (marking cached visible cells invalid).
4. …

As you can see it highly depends on the scenario you want to optimize for.

Now an important concerns to address: as you know, collection view recycles cells to optimize performance, if you're laying out all the views as soon as data source is set you will explode in memory.

Besides, is it an exercise or do you have a good reason not to trust `UICollectionView`?